# Repeated records when selecting datetime columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, I want to make this query:

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.date 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
AND table2.date >= to_date('01/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yy HH24:mi:ss')
```

the problem is table2.date is a datetime field, you can have two or more records of the same table2.id the same day (lets say, 01/28) and I just want to get one record of each id

I tried to solve my problem using the trunc method:

```
SELECT table1.name, TRUNC(table2.date)
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
AND TRUNC(table2.date) >= to_date('01/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yy')
```

And partly works, the repeated records aren't shown anymore, but my problem is I need the time part of the datetime field

How can I avoid the repeated records without using TRUNC?

Comment: if you need the time part, don't use trunc in the select clause. However, in your first query `to_date('01/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yy HH24:mi:ss')` should give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do this is to select one row by using `row_number()` and a subquery:

```
SELECT table1.name, t2.date 
FROM table1 JOIN
     (select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from table2 t
     ) t2
     ON table1.id=table2.id and seqnum = 1
WHERE table2.date >= to_date('01/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yy HH24:mi:ss')
```

However, you can do what you want with aggregation:

```
SELECT table1.name, min(table2.date)
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
AND table2.date >= to_date('01/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yy HH24:mi:ss')
group by table1.name, trunc(table2.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the trunc function from the select:

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.date
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
AND TRUNC(table2.date) >= to_date('01/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I did this query: select * from table2 where trunc(date) >= to_date('01/28/2013', 'mm/dd/yyyy') and table2.id=1 and I got many records, I just need one

Comment: you said yourself that "the repeated records aren't shown anymore" from this query (i simply copy/pasted from your post, removing the trunc from the select portion).  try select distinct ... using this query